# How to change font-weight of the text for the row in dataframe that matches the criteria which contains a mixture of float and string values?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

```
data = {'Rest (N=11570)': {4: '7369 (62.28%)', 1: '7016 (59.98%)', 37: '734 (6.14%)', 40: '9829 (79.09%)', 43: '37 (2.42%)', 5: '3080 (25.29%)', 6: '1273 (9.43%)', 12: '6992 (62.61%)', 15: '777 (5.47%)', 18: '332 (2.10%)', 21: '7 (3.44%)', 24: '2013 (14.39%)', 27: '290 (1.81%)', 30: '2048 (14.98%)', 33: '9 (3.85%)', 36: '353 (2.15%)', 351: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.14]', 354: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]', 357: '0.08 [0.04 - 0.14]', 168: '4.00 [3.72 - 4.30]', 171: '3.96 [3.62 - 4.27]', 174: '4.22 [3.92 - 4.50]', 177: '3.81 [3.44 - 4.12]', 180: '3.93 [3.60 - 4.20]'}, 'p_value': {4: '<0.001', 1: '0.005', 37: '0.056', 40: '<0.001', 43: '<0.001', 5: '<0.001', 6: '<0.001', 12: '<0.001', 15: '<0.001', 18: '<0.001', 21: '<0.001', 24: '<0.001', 27: '<0.001', 30: '<0.001', 33: '<0.001', 36: '<0.001', 351: '0.366', 354: '<0.001', 357: '0.008', 168: '0.012', 171: '0.004', 174: '0.220', 177: '0.047', 180: '0.025'}, 'ks_score': {4: nan, 1: nan, 37: nan, 40: nan, 43: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 12: nan, 15: nan, 18: nan, 21: nan, 24: nan, 27: nan, 30: nan, 33: nan, 36: nan, 351: '0.02', 354: '0.05', 357: '0.03', 168: '0.03', 171: '0.03', 174: '0.02', 177: '0.02', 180: '0.03'}}
```

I have this data for which I need to perform some styling using `pandas`. I'm trying to set text bold for the row which has `p_value < 0.05 or p_value == '<0.001'`. But I can't figure out how to do this. I'm reading the documentation from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html.

```
def __highlight_pvalue__(x):
        
        return ['font-weight:bold' if p == '<0.001' or float(p) < 0.05 else p for p in x]
```

call the styling function:

```
df.style.apply(__add_categorical_header_row__, row_idxs = row_indices, row_labels = row_labels, axis = None).apply(__highlight_pvalue__)
```

the function `__add_categorical_header_row__` works fine but when I add `__highlight_pvalue__` function, that's when I get the following error. I understand what the error means, but can't figure out how to solve it.

```
could not convert string to float: '7369 (62.28%)'
```

I also tried putting `try except` inside the `__hightlight_pvalue__` function without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your data dictionary should be corrected. All `nan` should be set as `np.nan`. Something for you have to think about next time when you create data for others to try!

Second, you added the style code with the function which you didn't really show what the function does. You didn't included the function detail with this.

Assuming your first function to style works, the problem with the function is that you're checking this for each column. Since you're using `.apply` without axis, it defaults to 0 i.e. columns - one column at a time. Since your first column seems to be string, it can't convert the value to string; hence, the error.

So, to fix this, your `__highlight_pvalue__` function needs to be changed to check only for pvalue.

```
data = {'Rest (N=11570)': {4: '7369 (62.28%)', 1: '7016 (59.98%)', 37: '734 (6.14%)', 40: '9829 (79.09%)', 43: '37 (2.42%)', 5: '3080 (25.29%)', 6: '1273 (9.43%)', 12: '6992 (62.61%)', 15: '777 (5.47%)', 18: '332 (2.10%)', 21: '7 (3.44%)', 24: '2013 (14.39%)', 27: '290 (1.81%)', 30: '2048 (14.98%)', 33: '9 (3.85%)', 36: '353 (2.15%)', 351: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.14]', 354: '0.08 [0.05 - 0.13]', 357: '0.08 [0.04 - 0.14]', 168: '4.00 [3.72 - 4.30]', 171: '3.96 [3.62 - 4.27]', 174: '4.22 [3.92 - 4.50]', 177: '3.81 [3.44 - 4.12]', 180: '3.93 [3.60 - 4.20]'}, 'p_value': {4: '<0.001', 1: '0.005', 37: '0.056', 40: '<0.001', 43: '<0.001', 5: '<0.001', 6: '<0.001', 12: '<0.001', 15: '<0.001', 18: '<0.001', 21: '<0.001', 24: '<0.001', 27: '<0.001', 30: '<0.001', 33: '<0.001', 36: '<0.001', 351: '0.366', 354: '<0.001', 357: '0.008', 168: '0.012', 171: '0.004', 174: '0.220', 177: '0.047', 180: '0.025'}, 'ks_score': {4: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 37: np.nan, 40: np.nan, 43: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: np.nan, 12: np.nan, 15: np.nan, 18: np.nan, 21: np.nan, 24: np.nan, 27: np.nan, 30: np.nan, 33: np.nan, 36: np.nan, 351: '0.02', 354: '0.05', 357: '0.03', 168: '0.03', 171: '0.03', 174: '0.02', 177: '0.02', 180: '0.03'}}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

def __highlight_pvalue__(x):
        
    if x.p_value == '<0.001' or float(x.p_value) < 0.05:
        return ['font-weight: bold'] * x.shape[0] # number of colums
    else: 
        return ''
```

The resulting dataframe

[image]

Comment: this is perfect. Sorry about the data and thank you for the suggestion. I appreciate it and will keep in mind the next time I post something over. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you!